# Testing Observables with jest

Tags: rxjs, observable, jestjs

How can I test Observables with Jest?

I have an Observable that fires ~every second, and I want to test that the 1st event is correctly fired, before jest times out.

```
const myObservable = timer(0, 1000); // Example here

it('should fire', () => {
  const event = myObservable.subscribe(data => {
    expect(data).toBe(0);
  });
});
```

This test passes, but it also passes if I replace with `toBe('anything')`, so I guess I am doing something wrong.

I tried using `expect.assertions(1)`, but it seems to be only working with Promises.

Comment: For async tests you can pass optional `done` parameter `it('should fire', done => {...})` that you call yourself when the test is done `subscribe(data => done())`.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There are some good examples in the Jest documentation about passing in an argument for the test. This argument can be called to signal a passing test or you can call fail on it to fail the test, or it can timeout and fail.

https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous.html

https://alligator.io/testing/asynchronous-testing-jest/

### Examples

**Notice I set the timeout to 1500ms**

```js
const myObservable = timer(0, 1000); // Example here

it('should fire', done => {
  myObservable.subscribe(data => {
    done();
  });
}, 1500); // Give 1500ms until it fails
```

**Another way to see if it fails using *setTimeout***

```js
const myObservable = timer(0, 1000); // Example here

it('should fire', done => {
  myObservable.subscribe(data => {
    done();
  });

  // Fail after 1500ms
  setTimeout(() => { done.fail(); }, 1500);
}, timeToFail);
```

Comment: Observables and async are very different concepts. Treating an observable as async works for simple use cases (like the one highlighted here). As soon as things become complicated your going to struggle to get these tests working correctly. That's why [`TestScheduler`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68470597/542251) exists

Answer (score 27):

My preferred way to test simple observables, without fake timers and timeouts, is to `async`, `await` and use [resolves](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#resolves) or [rejects](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects) on an expected converted promise.

```js
it('should do the job', async () => {
    await expect(observable
      .pipe(first())
      .toPromise())
      .resolves.toEqual(expectation);
});
```

In Rxjs 7 and onwards, you can use [lastValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/lastValueFrom) or [firstValueFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/firstValueFrom) for the promise convertion.

```js
it('should do the job', async () => {
    await expect(lastValueFrom(observable))
      .resolves.toEqual(expectation);
});
```

For more complex scenarios, check another [insightful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68470597/7322763)

Answer (score 10):

```js
test('Test name', (done) => {
  service.getAsyncData().subscribe((asyncData) => {
    expect(asyncData).toBeDefined();
    done();
  });
});
```

Comment: I used this scheme, but it has the problem of not calling done() when the expectation fails, resulting in a rather messy output. CTS_AE's solution is a way to solve this.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to test any RXJS observable (Jest or no) is to use the `TestScheduler` in `rxjs/testing`:

e.g.:

```js
import { TestScheduler } from 'rxjs/testing';
import { throttleTime } from 'rxjs/operators';
 
const testScheduler = new TestScheduler((actual, expected) => {
  // asserting the two objects are equal - required
  // for TestScheduler assertions to work via your test framework
  // e.g. using chai.
  expect(actual).deep.equal(expected);
});
 
// This test runs synchronously.
it('generates the stream correctly', () => {
  testScheduler.run((helpers) => {
    const { cold, time, expectObservable, expectSubscriptions } = helpers;
    const e1 = cold(' -a--b--c---|');
    const e1subs = '  ^----------!';
    const t = time('   ---|       '); // t = 3
    const expected = '-a-----c---|';
 
    expectObservable(e1.pipe(throttleTime(t))).toBe(expected);
    expectSubscriptions(e1.subscriptions).toBe(e1subs);
  });
});
```

From the [RXJS marble testing testing docs](https://rxjs.dev/guide/testing/marble-testing).

Trying to convert observables, etc. into promises works fine if you have a simple observable. As soon as things become more complicated you are going to struggle without using marble diagrams and the correct testing library.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an Angular approach using `fakeAsync`

Suppose we have a **FooService** with an Observable `closed$` that emit every time we call the `dismiss()` method of the service.

```js
@Injectable()
export class FooService {
    private closeSubject$ = new Subject<void>();
    public close$ = this.closeSubject$.asObservable();
    
    public dismiss() {
        this.closeSubject$.next();
    }
}
```

Then we can test the `close$` emission like this

```js
describe('FooService', () => {
    let fooService: FooService;

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            providers: [FooService]
        });
        fooService= TestBed.inject(FooService);
    });

    it('should emit a close event upon calling dismiss()', fakeAsync(() => {
        const callbackSpy = jest.fn();
        fooService.close$.subscribe(() => {
            callbackSpy();
        });
        fooService.dismiss();
        tick();
        expect(callbackSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches mentioned above

1. Taking argument done in our test and call it when we have tested.
2. Convert our observable to promise using firstValueFrom(myObs) or lastValueFrom(myObs). and use async await with them...

If we have multiple observables to test then we have to nest the observables in our test as we can call done() only once. In that case async await approach can come handy.
In this example when we call filter Customer all three observables emits values so we have to test all of them.

```js
it('Filter Customers based on Producers- Valid Case Promise way ', async () => {
  service.filterCustomers('Producer-1');

  await expect(firstValueFrom(service.customers$)).resolves.toEqual(['Customer-1']);

  await firstValueFrom(service.customers$).then((customers: string[]) => {
    expect(customers).toEqual(['Customer-1']);
    expect(customers.length).toBe(1);
  });

  await expect(firstValueFrom(service.products$)).resolves.toEqual([]);
  await expect(firstValueFrom(service.types$)).resolves.toEqual([]);
});
```